# Set custom environment variables in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am using AWS sagemaker, I have some secret keys and access keys to access some APIs that I don't want to expose directly in code.

What are the ways like environment variables etc., that can be used to hide these keys and I can use them securely, and how to set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS System Manager (SSM) is designed to store keys and tokens securely.

Depending on how your notebook is defined, you could [use the 'env' property](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/processing.html) directly or in [training data](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container.html#your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container-environment-variables), or you could access SSM directly from sagemaker. For example this Snowflake KB article explains how to fetch auth info from ssm: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Connecting-a-Jupyter-Notebook-Part-3